# Where can I get a large sample database for practising MySQL query optimization

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone give a reference to a substantially large sample database which I can import into MySQL to test and learn optimization and benchmarking? 
The database should have at least 6-8 tables with lots of foreign keys in between them, i.e a complete database. The `MySQL` `employees` database looked promising, but the download page has 3 download links, clicking on any of which opens a page in a browser with a god-awful amount of binary data, dont know what to do with that.

Comment: Well i cant but read this book help in optimizing Pragmatic SQL Antipatterns - Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming

Comment: 6 to 8 tables? Sweet :-)

Comment: It would be a bit of work to download and parse but the Enron case is online.  But sorry I cannot find the link right now.

Comment: That binary data is a dump. Right-click on the link and save it.

Comment: As Daniel says, right click on the binary data. The binary data is not a problem with the MySQL employees database, but rather with the website which hosts the data. It's 167MB, which I wouldn't call 'large', but it's larger then the typical Menagerie database used elsewhere.

Comment: Does anyone have a 10gb+ sample test file?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

StackOverflow itself publishes a database that could be used for this kind of testing. It's a fast [download](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) using BitTorrent since there's a lot of seeders.

Comment: Well, I visited your link. The data for one month alone is of size 4.3 GB?

Comment: Yeah, it's a robust real-world dataset that should provide a lot of opportunities for exploration.

Comment: This database is no longer available.

Comment: The host for this data has gone away. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213670/is-there-a-problem-with-the-clearbits-data-dump

Comment: And to use the data dump, see this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/26568/148318

Comment: download is tooooo slow... 4h left

Comment: If you use the torrent, you can select individual files to download, so that should shorten your download time

Comment: How to import it to PHPMyAdmin? it is formated on XML. I use db4free for candidate test purposes :D

Comment: @YohanesAI Parse the XML. The dump isn't in SQL format, it requires conversion.

Answer (score 19):

there is large dataset on [mysql website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html)

Answer (score 11):

Checkout https://launchpad.net/test-db/+download

it has about 6 tables i believe, suggest downloading the full archive.

The export data is around 167 MB.